# BASH version related issue

Tags: bash, unix

This statements works fine in BASH v. 4.1.7(1), but not in BASH v. 4.2.20(1)

```
num=${number:$counter:1}
```

I am getting "Bad Substitution" as the error. Any insights on why this is happening?
The objective is to do something similar to `${string:position:length}` for getting sub-string.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

The original code which had this line is added below (line 15)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter a number: "
read number

counter=0
answer=0
end=$(( ${#number} - 1 ))

echo -n "The sum of all digits of "
echo -n $number
echo -n " is "

while [ $counter -lt ${#number} ] ; do
num=${number:$counter:1}
if [ $counter -lt $end ] ; then
echo -n $num
echo -n "+"
else
echo -n $num
echo -n "="
fi
answer=$(( $answer + $num ))
counter=`expr $counter + 1`
done

echo $answer
```

Comment: What are the values of `number` and `counter`?

Comment: number is an input. counter is a variable which ranges from 0 to strlen of the number. Lets say number=123, and counter is 1.

Comment: Works fine for me in 3.2.48 - are you sure there aren't any other differences?

Comment: This is the original code which I have. This runs without any error in 4.1.7, but not in 4.2.20. Code added in the question.

Comment: How are you running the script? Are you certain that it is actually being run in Bash, and not a different shell (such as dash)?

Comment: Regression in bash? That's never happened before, wow ... :)

Comment: I ran as /bin/sh; changed to top to /bin/sh, and even went to bash shell to be sure I am in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the expression is fine with 4.2.20 when i tested it. maybe you have something in your env?

```
[localhost ~]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.20(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
[localhost ~]$ number=123
[localhost ~]$ counter=0
[localhost ~]$ echo $number
123
[localhost ~]$ num=${number:$counter:1}
[localhost ~]$ echo $num
1
```

Comment: I am not aware of anything. Is there anything particular which I can look for? Thanks for this.

Comment: that is odd. maybe you can save that as a script and run it as: bash -x test.sh, which i ran with no problems. if you run into error, please post the output and i will take a look.

Comment: I wonder if your bash package is somehow corrupt? You may want to reinstall it if it is just a test system. For a production system you need to be very careful.

Comment: If I run `bash a.sh` it runs fine. But, if I run `sh a.sh` I get this error. Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: your sh is not bash then. Do which sh, and do a ls -l on the file to find out.

Comment: Yes, /bin/sh is soft lined to /bin/dash. However, in the other computer where it worked, /bin/sh was soft linked to /bin/bash. If I may ask, what is Dash and how different it is from Bash?

Comment: Here is a good discussion of dash and how to avoid bash script errors. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-binbash-vs-bindash-vs-binshshell/